# Different Quality of Shuttlecock for World Championship/Olympics

Tags: equipment, tournaments, badminton

Why does the [BWF](http://www.bwfbadminton.org/)/[IOC](http://www.olympic.org/badminton) choos an even higher quality shuttlecock, that may only be used during international events like the World Championship and the Olympics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: to give the top badminton players of the world the best playing experience there is.

This particular shuttlecock is especially prepared for those events only. In [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tcgsBUDzHU) YouTube video, a match between Lee Hyun Il and Marc Zwiebler - Olympics 2008 round 16, a German commentator is making note of the special shuttlecock:

- [4'18"] only available for World Championships and Olympics
- [4'23"] heard from Martin Kranitz (German Olympic Sports Director) from supplier

Most probably the goose feathers are obtained from the northern part of the Republic of China. The cold conditions have an effect on the density of the feathers, giving extra insulation during cold weather.
When these types of feathers are used to prepare shuttlecock from, the shuttlecock will have a more precise and consistent fight behaviour, over the standard available feathers.